# Interface meeting derived class functionality without casting

Tags: c++

How can I get derived class object from my generic interface pointer. 
I do not want to type cast the generic interface in order to achieve above .

e.g:

```
class Base {}; // Has pure virtual functions and is my interface class

class Derived : public Base {}; // Additional functions .

Base *b = new Derived();
```

Now, I want to get derived pointer `Derived *derived` from `b` without casting. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're going to have to cast. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: If you are sure it is a `Derived` then `static_cast` if you are not sure then `dynamic_cast` and test.

Comment: @RichardCritten But that is already casting. (No idea why would avoid cast.)

Comment: My factory returns this base pointer to client . But client may want to work on derived interfaces and I do not want them to do casting explicitly .

Comment: @michalsrb that's why I posted a comment as it does not answer the question (even though it's correct).

Comment: If the clients may work on derived interfaces, it means that they already know the concrete type of the object. Why don't you return a `Derived*` directly?

Comment: IFactory *fac = IFactory::CreateFactory(DERIVEDCONTEXT);
Base* base = fac->CreateEntity();

If client does not type cast it he  will not use all the functionality I want him to use from derived .
Also I want to keep CreateEntity interface generic .

How can I restrict / impose him to work only with derived and avoiding the casting .

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems strange, I'd look for alternative options like returning Derived directly or moving the functions you need into base since you seem to need them.

If you still want to do that you could have something like:

```
class Derived;  // Forward declaration

class Base {
 public:
  virtual Derived* as_derived() { return null; }
...
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  Derived* as_derived() override { return this; }
};
```

Still, this looks like a hack and I would suggest casting instead. At least casting it's a common pattern and it will be easier for others to understand.